# Add node values in binary tree

Tags: java, node.js, recursion, sum, binary-tree

How do I print the sum of values under a node in a binary tree? Here's what I have so far:

```
public int sumT(Node nodo, int sum) {
    if (nodo == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int sum = suma + nodo.getLeft().getValor();
        int sum1 = sumT(nodo.getLeft(), sum);
        int sum2 = sumT(nodo.getRight(), sum1);
        return sum2;

    }

}
```

Comment: You declare `int sum` when sum is already a parameter of sumT.

Comment: `suma` does not exist as far as I can see.

Comment: Looks to me like when you hit a leaf node (or any node with no left branch), you're going to get an exception at `nodo.getLeft().getValor()` *before* the recursive call on the next line tests for a null Node.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int sumT(Node nodo)  {
  if  (nodo == null)
    return 0;
  return sumT(nodo.getLeft()) + sum(nodo.getRight()) + nodo.getValor();
}
```

This should be right. So you don´t have to set the sum as an argument in sumT.